# How to check if two variables refers to the same pandas object?

Tags: python, pandas

In this example, r1 and r2 refers to the same object but `assert(not r1 is r2)` returns false because their id are different. However, I would expect it to fail since r1 and r2 refers to the same object!!

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([0])
r1 = df.iloc[0]
r2 = df.iloc[0]
assert(not r1 is r2)
r1[0] = 1
assert(r1.equals(r2))
print(id(r1), id(r2))
```

```
>> 140547055257416 140547055258032
```

---

Explanations on why this happens can be found in [array slicing in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601107/array-slicing-in-numpy/19601170#19601170)

Comment: Use ’‘.copy()‘.   As to why see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I have rephrased it.

Comment: Sorry, this will answer your question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972633/in-pandas-does-iloc-method-give-a-copy-or-view

Comment: An interesting read but it does not show me how to check if two variables refers to the same pandas object.

Comment: you can call it a bug, but would you want a dict saving every iloc action you did to be saved so that the same ID will be given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.may_share_memory`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.may_share_memory.html) or [`np.shares_memory`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html#numpy-shares-memory) here

```
np.may_share_memory(r1, r2)
# True
```

Comment: What is the major difference between `shared memory` and `is`?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's do a simple experiment to see that `r1` and `r2` are actually the same objects in `pandas`'s sense

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3])
r1 = df.iloc[:,:1]
r2 = df.iloc[:,:1]

r1.iloc[2] = -10
r2.iloc[1] = -100
assert (not r1 is r2)

print(pd.concat((df,r1,r2),axis=1).to_string())
```

running this script, the output is

```
     0    0    0
0    0    0    0
1 -100 -100 -100
2  -10  -10  -10
3    3    3    3
```

this means `r1` and `r2` are considered the same object by `pandas`.

In fact, by running this script

```
unique_ids = []
for _ in range(1000):
    one_id = id(df.iloc[:,:1])
    unique_ids.append(one_id)
set(unique_ids)
```

you will see the length of `set(unique_ids)` is not 1 !!

According to @user2357112 supports Monica's comment under [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19601170/8366805)

> I don't think the ID you receive has any relation to the addresses of the array elements; it's the address of a header containing array metadata and a pointer to the storage used for the elements.

Basically, `r1` and `r2` are different objects referring to the same array elements.

Comment: You have illustrated my problem without answering it. You showed that r1 r2 are considered the same object but id are different.

Comment: @Chuan see my updated post, I guess `r1` and `r2` are headers containing array metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I marked Ch3steR's answer as correct because it answered the question.